# Save an IPicture to Stream, putting it on a TImage

Tags: delphi, com, delphi-10.4-sydney

Someone knows how can i get a IPicture and stores it in a TStream?

My goals is work with that on memory, and shows to the user in a TImage.

Using the *OleSavePictureFile* the image can be saved to any format (PNG, BMP, JPG etc), but, saving on disk. Someone knows how get the IPicture and save it to the stream and put it on a TImage?

I've tried by this way

```
// Obtaining the IPicture
  var LPicture := DPBiometria.DPSC.ConvertToPicture(pSample) as IPicture;

// This line saves the image correctly, but i dont want this way.
//  OleSavePictureFile(IPictureDisp(LPicture), 'D:\teste.jpg');

// Trying stores it on the stream and put on a bitmap or show on a TImage
  var LStream := TBytesStream.Create;
  var LOleG := TOleGraphic.Create;
  LOleG.Picture := LPicture;
  LOleG.SaveToStream(LStream);

  // When loading it on a TImage, it doesnt shows...
  // When loadgin on a TBitMap or TJPegImage, and trying to
  // save to a file, its saved with 0 bytes.

  // The TImage doesnt shows the image
  SomeTImage.LoadFromFile(LStream);

  // Saved with 0 bytes
  var Lbmp := TBitmap.Create;
  Lbmp.LoadFromStream(LStream);
  Lbmp.SaveToFile('D:\testeStream.bmp');
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Most likely you need an [`IStream`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/istream+delphi), too, not a `TStream`. How is your `DPBiometria` declared so people are actually able to recompile your code sample?

Comment: Thanks AmigoJack, I'll try use this.

Comment: The DPBiometria is a record with variables from a unit with access to a COM/Ole device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the `TBytesStream.Position` property back to 0 after saving the image to the stream and before loading the stream.

That being said, if all you want to do is display the `IPcture` in a `TImage`, you don't need to save the `IPicture` to a stream and then load the stream into a `TBitmap`.  Since `TOleGraphic` derives from `TGraphic`, you can simply assign the `TOleGraphic` directly to the `TImage.Picture.Graphic` property, eg:

```
var LPicture := DPBiometria.DPSC.ConvertToPicture(pSample) as IPicture;

var LOleG := TOleGraphic.Create;
try
  LOleG.Picture := LPicture;
  SomeTImage.Picture.Graphic := LOleG;
finally
  LOleG.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Makes sense... Right. I'll try this way. I want save it in a class field, then, using the class, I'll apply it on a TImage, this is why I'm trying use TStream, in this class, the field its a TStream/TBytesStream. Thank you a lot, I'll reply here if it works for me.

Comment: @jcaique In that case, why not use `TPicture` instead as the class member, rather than  `TStream`? You can assign a `TPicture` to a `TImage.Picture`

Comment: Thanks you so much. When in problem, we dont see basic things. In my class, i change the data type TStream to TGraphic, then i used the TOleGraphic object to set it, applied to the TImage and worked.